# Is the definition correct?

Tags: definition

I'm writing a B.Sc. thesis in computer science and needed to include the definition of Cartesian product. I wrote it according to the following and wonder if it is correct:

> Cartesian product - The set of all possible permutations of two other
>   sets.

It sounds too simple and I didn't find it written exactly like that but when I look at definitions it seems to be the above meaning. Or did I misunderstand?

If A and B are two sets then the Cartesian product is the set of points $\big\{\{a1,b1\},\{a2,b2\},\dots\big\}$ excluding the points $\{b1,a1\}$ etc.

Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I wouldn't understand "the set of possible permutations of two other sets" :-(

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you agree with the alternative definition _"The set of all ordered pairs from two other sets"_ ? I hope we understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**remark**

$$\{a,b\}=\{b,a\} $$

but

$$(a,b)\neq (b,a) $$

$$A\times B=\{(a,b)\;:\; a\in A , b\in B\} $$

Comment: Maybe this text is better: _The set of all ordered pairs of two other sets._. I tried to use plain English instead of symbols in my report.